# Can I set my WebAPI route to require that either parameter X or parameter Y is included?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api-routing

For the GET function in my controller I want to require that a name be passed in. For the PUT function I want to require that the id be passed in (with the object in the message body). For example:

```
GetObject(string name)
PutObject(int id, Object obj)
```

Can I create a route that requires either the name or the id parameter to exist? In pseudocode:

```
routeTemplate: api/{controller}/{name}|{id}
```

Or what is the best way to route this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I might suggest having a look at the [AttributeRouting](http://attributerouting.net/) package to solve your problems if you're using HTTP verbs RESTfully. It allows for some pretty advanced routing including conditionals like you're looking for.

Comment: Perfect! This package let me decorate the functions as follows: `[GET("api/Object/{name}")]` for the Get function and `[PUT("api/Object/{id}")]` for the Put function. Thanks!